# Drools list type field

Tags: java, drools

How can I add a field of type list in my xmlrequest?

for example I have following class

```
public class app{
    private java.util.List<java.lang.Integer> test;
    private int age;
     public int getAge()
     {
        return this.age;
      }

    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
     }
    public java.util.List<java.lang.Integer> getTest()
      {
         return this.test;
       }

   public void setTest(java.util.List<java.lang.Integer> test)
        {
            this.test = test;
          }

        }
```

and following is xmlrequest format.

```
<batch-execution lookup="defaultStatelessKieSession">
 <insert>
<com.redhat.loandemo.app>
  <age>41</age>
  <test></test>
   </com.redhat.loandemo.app>
  </insert>
  <fire-all-rules/>
   <get-objects out-identifier="output"/>
  </batch-execution>
```

here test is list of integers. so how can I add it to xmlrequest?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML request should be:

```
<batch-execution lookup="defaultStatelessKieSession">
<insert>
    <com.redhat.loandemo.app>
        <age>41</age>
        <test>1</test>
        <test>2</test>
        <test>3</test>
        <test>4</test>
    </com.redhat.loandemo.app>
</insert>
<fire-all-rules/>
<get-objects out-identifier="output"/>
```